# How to call mongoose's CRUD methods inside an instance method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) shows this example to create a new document

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);

var small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });
small.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
})

// or

Tank.create({ size: 'small' }, function (err, small) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
})
```

The problem I am having is that I do not yet have a `Tank`. I am defining an instance method and I want to do a `Tank.create()` inside of it. How can I call this `create` and other similar methods from within an instance method?

Comment: In general, it probably is not a best practice to call Tank.create from within an instance method. You can refer to the instance with `this` and call `save` on it to update the instance, but the creation of a new tank should not really happen from the instance of another tank.

Answer (score 1):

This works but seems like a hack:

`this.constructor.create()`

**Edit:** These are custom instance methods (not built in) so the the model needs to be called.

```
this.model('Tank').create()
```